# Export solution in form assigning variable with subscript

Tags: export, import

I can find solutions of linear equations like below:

```
sol = Flatten[  Solve[{2 Subscript[C, 1] + 2 Subscript[C, 2] == -1, 
     2 Subscript[C, 1] + 3 Subscript[C, 2] == 1}]] 
Export["sol.csv", sol, "CSV"]
sol = Import["sol.csv", "CSV"]
```

How can i export  and import solution in Mathematica with appearing function subscript in list.(when i import solution function of subscript appear in my solution).

Comment: How are you currently exporting and importing.  Please edit your post and provide the code.

Answer (score 2):

`CSV` (Comma-separated values) uses comma as delimiter and, hence, interpreting the comma in `Subscript[C, 1]` as a field separator, exports `Subscript[C, 1] -> -5/2` as `{"Subscript[C", " 1] -> -5/2"}`

```
sol = Flatten[Solve[{2 Subscript[C, 1] + 2 Subscript[C, 2] == -1, 
    2 Subscript[C, 1] + 3 Subscript[C, 2] == 1}]]
Export["sol.csv", sol, "CSV"];
imported = Import["sol.csv", "CSV"]
```

> {{"Subscript[C", " 1] -> -5/2"}, {"Subscript[C", " 2] -> 2"}}

this can be seen in the file `sol.csv`
[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can use import it as `TSV` (Tab-separated values) instead to avoid this issue:

```
imported2 = Import["sol.csv", "TSV"]
```

> {{"Subscript[C, 1] -> -5/2"}, {"Subscript[C, 2] -> 2"}}

```
ToExpression@imported2
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
sol // ToString // ToExpression // TableForm // TraditionalForm
```

will give you

$C_1 \rightarrow -\frac{5}{2}$

$C_2 \rightarrow 2$.

`ToString` converts it to a string. `ToExpression` is the most important one, converting it to a mathematical expression. `TableForm` and `TraditionalForm` will make it pretty. I think you are exporting as `.csv` and that's why the imported format is not usable. Instead, you can use `.dat` or `.txt`.

Comment: It doesn't work if we have two or three or more subscripts

Comment: @Farid, Did you save it as `.dat`? Or you are insisting on using `.csv`? Provide an example, please.

Comment: I save it in dat form and arise  same problem